# Can I substitute "by defeating/obtained after defeating" for "over" in the sentence "Their win over the first place team was unexpected."?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Their win **over** the first place team was unexpected.

I want to put my own definition of "over" in the sentence.

My definition is—"by defeating" or "obtained after defeating"

So the sentence is—"Their win by defeating the first place team was unexpected."

Comment: Surely if they defeat the first place team, you'd expect them to win? Your sentence is ambiguous and hence sounds a bit weird.

Comment: @StuartF so, What should be the definition for "over" in this case??

Comment: @StuartF what's your opinion of this sentence —**France swept to a 6–2 win over(=by defeating) Denmark.**

Comment: Their defeat of the x team was unexpected. [grammar: What should the definition of "over" be.]

Answer (score 0):

> Their win **over** the first place team was unexpected.

We can't replace *over* with *by defeating*.

We can, however, say

> Their **defeating** the first place team was unexpected.

Some competitions are played in a round-robin format, that is, all the teams play against every other team; whichever gets the highest point tally wins the tournament.   There is a possibility that a team initially with low point tally leaps to become the champion by beating the team which was the best until before that match.

I don't think the OP is referring to that.  To describe that, we may say

> Their **winning the tournament by defeating the first place team** (on the final day) was unexpected.

Comment: So can I say— "Their win by causing the first place team to fail was unexpected".

Comment: Winning a match means defeating the other team (the first place team in this case).  Why would we need to repeat the understood "causing the first place team to fail"?

Comment: In place of "over",I want to put this definition

Comment: Also, just "their defeat of x was unexpected".

Answer (score 0):

The preposition **by** can introduce the means or method used to accomplish an end or achieve a result. A sentence that uses **by** in this sense will express both the end result and the means by which it is achieved.

> By drinking a tall glass of water <sup>means</sup> he slaked his thirst <sup>result</sup>.
>
> He slaked his thirst <sup>result</sup> by drinking a tall glass of water <sup>means</sup>.

As you can see, the phrase headed with **by** can come before or after the clause that expresses the result.

The means and result are not clearly expressed in your proposed sentence, which is tautological and doesn't make good sense:

> *France swept to a 6-2 win by defeating Denmark.
>
> *By defeating Denmark France swept to a 6-2 win.

You could write something like this:

> By defeating Denmark 6-2, France swept to first place in the league.
>
> France swept to first place in the league by defeating Denmark 6-2.